# Working on K-means clustering on textual Data, want to Map the clusters with the Data

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am working on df having two columns: Ticket Number and Description(on which we want to cluster). Using below for the task i.e to map the cluster with the Df

```
#setup kmeans clustering
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5, n_init = 10,init='k-means++', max_iter = 200)
    #fit the data 
    kmeans.fit(vec_text)
    #this loop transforms the numbers back into words
    common_words = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:,-1:-11:-1]
    for num, centroid in enumerate(common_words):
        print(str(num) + ' : ' + ', '.join(words[word] for word in centroid))

    labels=kmeans.labels_
#trying to map here
    

model=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(description,labels)),columns=['description','cluster'])
    print(kmeans.sort_values(by=['cluster']))
```

Can you please help here to suggest a better way to map the result of the cluster with the data?